# Why is $A \sin( \omega t)$ an SHM equation while $A \sin(k x- \omega t)$ is a wave equation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, waves, harmonic-oscillator

How does such a small change in the sine function change what it represents?

Comment: Neither $A \sin wt$ nor $A \sin (kx-wt)$ are equations, they are expressions. What expressions represent depend on the context. I'm having a hard time understanding the point of your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, neither of the above are "equations", but instead they are solutions to equations. The first solution is a displacement function of time, it is a solution to the ordinary differential equation (ODE)
$$ \ddot u(t) = - w^2u(t) $$
which is a simple equation for harmonic motion, arising, e.g., in oscillations of a spring.

Now, the second solution is a displacement function of both space and time, so a 2D function, and thus it must be a solution to a 2D Partial Differential Equation (PDE). For example, it is a solution to the above-mentioned wave-equation PDE

$$ \ddot u(x,t) = v^2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$$

when one plugs in the solution, one should find the dispersion relation $$ w = vk$$

Comment: So x= Acos (wt) does not satisfy the wave differential equation? With regard to the same, is it not a solution since it is a function of x and not y?

Comment: x = A cos(wt) is a function of 1 variable, namely x = f(t). The wave equation can only be satisfied by a function of 2 variables, namely y = f(x,t). The displacement variable y is not the same as a parameter x. Thus in a simple wave equation there are 3 variables - x,y,t, and the wave equation is the relation between them